# My cursor moves without me touching it

Tags: debian, kde, synaptics-touchpad

This is a Lenovo r60.

I suspect this is a hardware issue because the same thing happened on my previous OS (Linux Mint) and now its happening again on my new OS (Debian Lenny).

After logging in my cursor will inevitably start gliding, on its own, to either the bottom or top left corner of my screen.

On reboot it will stay put, but only for a non-exact amount of time (sometimes a few mins sometimes an hour).

How can I troubleshoot this and possibly fix it?

Here is some possibly related devices in /proc/bus/input/devices:

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=17aa Product=5054 Version=4101
N: Name="ThinkPad Extra Buttons"
P: Phys=thinkpad_acpi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd rfkill event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=33
B: KEY=18040000 0 10000000000000 0 1501b02102004 c000080021104000 10e000000000000 0
B: MSC=10
B: SW=8

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=81b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event10 
B: PROP=1
B: EV=b
B: KEY=6420 30000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=11000003

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000a Version=0000
N: Name="TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
P: Phys=synaptics-pt/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=7
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
```

My thinkpad seems to be event 10 so I ran `evtest /dev/input/event10`

Here is the output of evtest on event10 when my cursor is gliding without me touching the mouse pad:

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x11 vendor 0x2 product 0x7 version 0x81b1
Input device name: "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 272 (BTN_LEFT)
    Event code 273 (BTN_RIGHT)
    Event code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
    Event code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP)
    Event code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value   5876
      Min     1472
      Max     5472
      Resolution      93
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value   5041
      Min     1408
      Max     4448
      Resolution     125
    Event code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      255
    Event code 28 (ABS_TOOL_WIDTH)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max       15
Properties:
  Property type 0 (INPUT_PROP_POINTER)
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1448144554.677595, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 1
Event: time 1448144554.677595, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1448144554.845659, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 0
Event: time 1448144554.845659, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1448144554.984782, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 1
Event: time 1448144554.984782, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1448144555.570349, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 0
Event: time 1448144555.570349, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1448144555.878473, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 1
Event: time 1448144555.878473, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1448144556.028886, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 0
Event: time 1448144556.028886, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1448144556.166404, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 3
Event: time 1448144556.166404, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1448144556.335002, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 1
Event: time 1448144556.335002, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1448144556.476101, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 0
Event: time 1448144556.476101, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1448144556.633217, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 1
```

Comment: What laptop model is that?

Comment: Does the issue not occur at all if you disable the touchpad? If it does, it could be that the track point is stuck. Do you use the track point or the touch pad?

Comment: I use the touch pad but that is a good idea. How would I disable the touch pad, but not the track point?

Comment: Added the model laptop

Comment: Dear user1028270, I only used Ubuntu with my thinkpad, there I could just use fn+f8. In my case, this only disabled the touchpad. The r60 also has fn+f8 as the default shortcut.

Comment: If disabling just the touchpad is not possible in your current OS, you could consider making an Ubuntu bootable  USB, since I'm sure you can try it there. Then you can find out for sure whether the issue is a hardware one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is still doubt either this is hardware / software issue. As concern hardware then here is little reason to this problem because I faced this issue in my macbook.

There are small sensors in touchpad which sense activity upon touch. sometime dust particles goes inside the touchpad so when those particles move touchpad start sensing them and in result courser start jagging.

So what I did; I open the touchpad and wash it with eathr or alcohol but not water try to remove dust with brush from corners. when you think this is done then reinstall touchpad.